# Phaser Tilemaps

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I have tried the code below and the tileset doesn't load.

```js
  this.game.physics.startSystem(Phaser.Physics.ARCADE);
  map = game.add.tilemap('tilemap');
    map.addTilesetImage('floor', 'tiles');
    layer = map.createLayer('GroundLayer');
    layer.resizeWorld();
```

Comment: There is way too little information here for anyone to be able to answer your question. On which line of your code does the error occur? Did the tilemap and tiles files load correctly? The names are case-sesitive, so maybe you made a typo in the `GroundLayer` name? etc.

Comment: I've solved the error now, but the tileset still doesn't load. GroundLayer was spelled correctly, the rest of the game worked perfectly well just not the tilemap.

Answer (score 0):

I found this code worked

```js
this.game.physics.startSystem(Phaser.Physics.ARCADE);
  this.map = game.add.tilemap('tilemap');
    this.map.addTilesetImage('floor', 'floor');
    this.layer = this.map.createLayer('GroundLayer');
    game.physics.enable(this.map, Phaser.Physics.ARCADE);
    this.map.setCollisionBetween(0, 1, true, "GroundLayer");
    this.layer.resizeWorld();
```